# Overwriting line in file with special characters

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to change part of line in txt file. It is working, but if the line in the file contains special characters like ?!( its not working
What is wrong?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class nomarks
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FileInputStream fstream;
        try
        {
            fstream = new FileInputStream("readme.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String oldText = "i have !? in my text";
            String textToChange = "cant solve the problem";
            String line;
            String holeFile = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null)
            {
                holeFile += line + "\r\n";
            }
            br.close();
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("readme.txt");
            String newtext = holeFile.replaceAll(oldText, textToChange);
            writer.write(newtext);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: which text you want to replace

Comment: :p i see this now okk let me try it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `replace` in your case:

```
String newtext = holeFile.replace(oldText, textToChange);
```

`replaceAll` uses `regexp` (and you have question mark in your string), that's why you can have a problem.

See docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29),

Answer (score 1):

You can use `holeFile.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(oldText), textToChange)`

Answer (score 0):

The *problem* with the [`.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is that it takes a regular expression as first parameter. So, assuming that you want to match exactly `i have !? in my text`. you would need to change it into a regular expression friendly (if you will) text.

So, in short, you would need to replace this: `i have !? in my text` with this: `i have !\\? in my text`